# DevTools Profiler tab not visible for a react-native application

Tags: react-native

According to react-native changelog, the React Profiler is supporting in react-native since version 0.57 (https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#tooling-updates).

I have an application using react native 0.59.1, and the profiler is working. However, I am not able to view the profiler tab in chrome's react dev tools (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html#profiling-an-application).

I tried to do it with the app running on a genymotion emulator (on Windows), on Samsung Galaxy S6 and on a Xiaomi Mi A1 but it is not visible for any of these.

Does it work for you? On which smartphone type and which version of react native?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution is simple, if you know where to read.

react-native doesn't work with the chrome extension, but with the stand alone version:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/v3/packages/react-devtools#usage-with-react-native